# How do I initialize a struct using the new C99 syntax?

Tags: c, struct, c99

I'm trying to initialize a struct using the new C99 initialization syntax. However, I'm getting a compilation error "expected expression before '{' token" from GCC 4.9.2 whenever I compile code that is setup like this:

```
// *.h file
typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int y;
} SPoint;

typedef struct
{
   SDL_Window* window;
   SPoint position;
} SWindow;

// *.c file
SWindow* create(int x, int y) {
SWindow* window = malloc(sizeof(SWindow));
// snip
(*window) = { .window = sdlWindow,
              .position = { .x = x,
                            .y = y }};
// snip
```

If I add a "(SWindow)" in front of the initializer, it compiles fine. Other than some syntactical ugliness (which if you have some advice on that, I'd appreciate it), I don't see just what I'm missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(*window) = { .window = sdlWindow,
              .position = { .x = x,
                            .y = y }};
```

is not initialization. It is assignment. By using

```
(*window) = (SWindow) { .window = sdlWindow,
                        .position = { .x = x,
                                      .y = y }};
```

you are asking the compiler to create a temporary object, and then using the temporary object to do the assignment.

Comment: Of course, OP could also have written `SWindow window = { .window = sdlWindow, ` etc.